# Add sequential number to wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, extend

I need to extend the wp_nav_menu function a bit.

I have a menu structure like this:

li data-slide="1">Home
li data-slide="2">About us
li data-slide="3">Portfolio
li data-slide="4">Team
li data-slide="5">Blog
li data-slide="6">Services
li data-slide="7">Contact

and I need those numbers from the "**data-slide**" attribute to be **incremented** in that order. I also need to add the attribute "data-slide"  to each LI (list) element, like in the example bellow.
If somebody could help me that would be great.

Regards